# cannot convert void to int

Tags: c#, java, android, unity-game-engine

I'm making my first Android plug in for unity and I've ran into one issue I can't resolve. Right now, this plug in is extremely simple. All it does it return an increasing number but with the method being create in a native Android file. Then I call this method from inside Unity to see the number rise.

Here is my code. The Android Java file:

```
package com.test.app;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Config;
import android.util.Log;

public class PluginTest extends UnityPlayerActivity
{
    private static final String TAG = "PluginTest_Unity";
    private static int number = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle myBundle)
{
    super.onCreate(myBundle);
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    if(Config.DEBUG)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
    }
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    if(Config.DEBUG)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop");

    }
    super.onStop();
}

public static int getNumber()
{
    number++;
    return number;
}
```

}

My C# file in Unity:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NumberExample : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GUIText number_output_text;
    AndroidJavaClass pluginTutorialActivityJavaClass;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        AndroidJNI.AttachCurrentThread();
        pluginTutorialActivityJavaClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.test.app.PluginTest");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        int number = pluginTutorialActivityJavaClass.CallStatic("getNumber");
        number_output_text.text = "nr: " + number;
    }
}
```

However, when I try to build my program in Unity it complains that I cannot convert a void to an int with the following line:

```
int number = pluginTutorialActivityJavaClass.CallStatic("getNumber");
```

Can anyone see the change I need to make with my code?

Comment: Callstatic is void. See docs: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaObject.CallStatic.html

Comment: Do you perhaps want `GetStatic<T>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaObject.CallStatic.html):

> To call a static method with a non-void return type, use the generic
>   version.

```
// Create a java.lang.String object, and call static method valueOf(float value).
function Start() {
    var jo = new AndroidJavaObject("java.lang.String");
    var valueString = jo.CallStatic<string>("valueOf", 42.f);
}
```

You should probably call

```
int number = pluginTutorialActivityJavaClass.CallStatic<int>("getNumber");
```

Comment: Beat me by the millisecond with this ctrl-c ctrl-v :-)